# How do I display a high dpi plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a retina MacBook and I would like to display plots in Matplotlib that are high-dpi so that the plots don't look blurry on my screen.

When using `set_matplotlib_formats` and setting it to `svg`, everything looks perfect: the image is crisp and scalable, and the text size looks fine. However, scalable graphics are often not convenient when I'm making a plot that has hundreds of thousands of elements.

[image]

Setting it to `png` with a `dpi` of 300 doesn't work well since it makes the image bigger. The image is also not crisp—although the plot is rendered at high dpi, is it displayed quite large and thus the displayed dpi is low.

[image]

Trying retina seems to fix this issue (the plot size is correct and the image is crisp). However, it makes the text size really small (compare it to the `svg` option):

[image]

Is there an option that sizes the plot and the text correctly like `svg` but which doesn't use scalable graphics? Here is the code for reference:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
%matplotlib inline
set_matplotlib_formats('retina')

plt.plot(range(5))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `matplotlib_set_formats` however... If you are making an svg and you come across a pcolormesh that has "too much" data, you can use the `rasterized=True` kwarg to just rasterize that artist.  Many artists have this option. Then you get the best of both a raster format and a vector format.

Comment: This is excellent advice, thank you! Do you know of a way to increase the dpi of the rasterized portion itself though? It seems like it goes back to that issue of being blurry on a high-dpi screen

Comment: You can set the dpi of the figure when it is created or in your marpltilibrc. The renderer should then use that dpi for rasters

Comment: This works very well, thanks. If you write what you've commented as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.